# Increment number in each click of button in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hi I am trying to a set a counter for each click to increment by one but it is not responding. This is my code. I am following this tutorial https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/build-your-first-android-app/#7

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
   // View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    View fragmentFirstLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    showCountTextView = fragmentFirstLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_first);
   // button = view.findViewById(R.id.toast_button);
    button = view.findViewById(R.id.count_button);


    view.findViewById(R.id.count_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            countMe(view);
        }
    });
    return  fragmentFirstLayout; //view;
}
private void countMe(View view) {
    // Get the value of the text view
    String countString = showCountTextView.getText().toString();
    // Convert value to a number and increment it
    Integer count = Integer.parseInt(countString);
    count++;
    // Display the new value in the text view.
    showCountTextView.setText(count.toString());
}
```

Comment: pass `showCountTextView` to `countMe` func

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fragment`: all element need to get via `view`

```
View yourView = view.findViewById(R.id.text_first);
```

`activity`: can directly access the element

```
View yourView = findViewById(R.id.text_first);
```

Your case is `fragment`, so there are two ways to do it

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

    View showCountTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.text_first);
    Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.count_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            countMe(view, showCountTextView); // 1
            countMe(view); // 2
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

1. pass `showCountTextView` to `countMe` func

```
private void countMe(View view, View showCountTextView) {
    String countString = showCountTextView.getText().toString();
    Integer count = Integer.parseInt(countString);
    count++;

    showCountTextView.setText(count.toString());
}
```

or get the `TextView` by `view`

2. get `showCountTextView` from `view`

```
private void countMe(View view) {
    View showCountTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.text_first);

    String countString = showCountTextView.getText().toString();
    Integer count = Integer.parseInt(countString);
    count++;

    showCountTextView.setText(count.toString());
}
```

Comment: when I tried to use the 2. it shows cannot resolve element getText and setText()

Comment: @Jalloh u can print `showCountTextView` what is the value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210212/discussion-between-jalloh-and-donald-wu).

Answer (score 0):

Two possible cases here.

It seems, *view* and *fragmentFirstLayout* are over one another on z-axis.
So when you are clicking *fragmentFirstLayout* will be clicked not the *view*.

OR

*View* is not infalted as fragment view at all.

Comment: You should set listener on *fragmentFirstLayout*

Answer (score 0):

You should just continue with the tutorial. They solve the problem in step 4. If you still have problems here is FirstFragment.java file, works for me.

```
package com.example.DTPM;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;

import com.example.DTPM.databinding.FragmentFirstBinding;

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

private FragmentFirstBinding binding;

TextView showCountTextView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState
) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View fragmentFirstLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    // Get the count text view
    showCountTextView = fragmentFirstLayout.findViewById(R.id.textview_first);

    return fragmentFirstLayout;

}

public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

//        binding.buttonFirst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this)
//                        .navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment);
//            }
//        });
        view.findViewById(R.id.toast_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                myToast.show();
            }
        });
        view.findViewById(R.id.count_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                countMe(view);
            }
        });
    }

    private void countMe(View view){

    //View showCountTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textview_first)
    // Get the value of the text view
    String countString = showCountTextView.getText().toString();
    // Convert value to a number and increment it
    Integer count = Integer.parseInt(countString);
    count++;
    // Display the new value in the text view.
    showCountTextView.setText(count.toString());
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    binding = null;
}
```

}